# Convert Number To String (Charset Supplied) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Update:

The following code works perfectly until $char.to_text encounters an integer greater than 55,834,574,847.

```
alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$char={
    to_num:function(s,c){
        var l=c.length,o={};
        c.split('').forEach(function(a,i){
            o[a]=i
        });
        return s.split('').reduce(function(r,a){
            return r*l+o[a]
        },0)
    },
    to_text:function(i,c){
        var l=c.length,s='';
        do{
            s=c[i%l]+s; // i%l
            i/=l;
            i|=0
        }while(i!==0);
        return s
    }
};
```

Here is a quick snip:

```
$char.to_num("military",alpha) => 98987733674
$char.to_text(98987733674,alpha) => "undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedy"
```

Manually iterating the above code should generate a normal response, why does it yield this "undefined..." string, is it simply because it's a large number operation for JS?

Comment: You know, you could've just used `parseInt(a, 27)`…

Comment: @Bergi, not really, you would get 1 ... 9 as well. this would need some shifting.

Comment: @NinaScholz: OK, followed by a `replace`… But given he includes `0` in his charset, I don't think 1-9 would have mattered.

Comment: The only reason I don't use parseInt() is because I am handling a lot of different charset conversions (alphabetical to numerical to hex to custom charsets such as "qaz0xsw1edc2vfr3tgb4nhy5ujm6kio7lp-89")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proposal with a rewritten `hash` function, which uses an object `o` as simplified `indexOf` and a simple loop for the return value.

The wanted function `ihash` uses a single `do ... until` loop. It uses the remainder of the value and the length as index of the given charcter set. The value is then divided by the lenght of the caracter set and the integer part is taken for the next iteration, if not equal zero.

```js
function hash(s) {
    var c = '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        l = c.length,
        o = {};

    c.split('').forEach(function (a, i) {
        o[a] = i;
    });
    return s.split('').reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r * l + o[a];
    }, 0);
}

function ihash(i) {
    var c = '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        l = c.length,
        s = '';

    do {
        s = c[i % l] + s;
        i = Math.floor(i / l);
    } while (i !== 0);
    return s;
}

document.write(hash('0') + '<br>');          // => 0
document.write(hash('a') + '<br>');          // => 1
document.write(hash('hi') + '<br>');         // => 225
document.write(hash('world') + '<br>');      // => 12531838
document.write(hash('freecode') + '<br>');   // => 69810159857

document.write(ihash(0) + '<br>');           // => '0'
document.write(ihash(1) + '<br>');           // => 'a'
document.write(ihash(225) + '<br>');         // => 'hi'
document.write(ihash(12531838) + '<br>');    // => 'world'
document.write(ihash(69810159857) + '<br>'); // => 'freecode'
```

Comment: This snippet works almost perfectly; however, I'm afraid it stops working if the integer is greater than 55834574847. Can't figure out why, I assume it has to do with JS's number environment (it's not particularly good at handling large numbers/floats..). Posting an update to display results

Comment: @JoBro, please see edit. i changed the implicit cast to integer with `Math.floor`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly (: I'm still curious though, what did changing " i |= 0 " to " i = Math.floor(i / l) " do exactly?

Comment: it was a problem with [signed 32 bit integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers) and [max safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). the former is shorter in range and floor takes bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code for getting the string back. It's similar to convert numbers of different base.

```
   var txt = function(n, charset) {
        var s =""
        while (n > 0) {
            var r = n % charset.length;
            n = n / charset.length;
            s += charset[r];
         }
         return s;
     }
```